# Can't have access to classes which implement an interface in client side in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

In my wcf service I'm using a class (InputClass) which contains a list of objects which implement an interface (IProperty):

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    OutputClass CanBeImported(InputClass inputObject);
}

[DataContract]
public class InputClass 
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<IProperty> Properties { get; set; }
} 

public interface IProperty
{
}
```

I have several classes which implement IProperty interface

```
[DataContract]
public class Class1 : IProperty 
{        
    [DataMember]
    public string name1 { get; set; }
} 

[DataContract]
public class Class2 : IProperty 
{        
    [DataMember]
    public int number { get; set; }
}
```

the problem is that I can't see class1 and class2 in client side in my service.
How can I send these classes to client side in a way that client can use class1 and class2 and fill InputClass properties. I'll be appreciated if someone help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

Add `[KnownType(typeof(Class1))]` and `[KnownType(typeof(Class2))]` to IProperty interface.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it says attribute KnownType is only valid on 'class, struct' declarations.